# How to extract WHITE color density or number of pixels from an image in python using openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Considering me a noob in programming please accept my apology if my query seems to be irrelevant or too basic.
Actually, I want to compare these two pictures (embedded in a single [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKGwf.png)). One has all solid white region and other one has some black patches.
What I am targeting is to extract the no. of white color pixels or density of while color so that I can distinguish among these two images by getting values of white color density but I don't know if this approach is right or wrong.
Right now I have a code that mask and binary inverse the input image.
Here's my code
Complete procedure can be seen [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukgVU.png)

```
def label():
    image = cv2.imread("2121.bmp")
    ROIs = cv2.selectROIs("Select Rois", image)
    ROIs = ROIs.tolist()
    print(ROIs)
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
    i = 0
    for rect in ROIs:
        (x, y, w, h) = ROIs[i]
        i = i + 1
        cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), 255, -1)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    masked = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
    masked = cv2.threshold(masked, 100, 225, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]  # 100, 225

    cv2.imshow("Image02", masked)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


label()
```